# How to exclude a row based on a partial string match?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table of jobs that has a longtext field named "keywords".

I am trying to form a SELECT statement where I can match on some keywords while excluding others.

For example, I need the SQL for "Give me all the jobs where the keywords contain the word 'portraits', but exclude those jobs that have the word 'outdoors'."

Thanks!  [and if the question needs to be modified, or additional info needed, just let me know.]

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
. . . WHERE keywords LIKE '%portraits%' AND keywords NOT LIKE '%outdoors%' . . .
```

A better approach might be to define a separate table of keywords for jobs. It would have one row for each job/keyword combination. With proper indexing, you can greatly speed up the lookup of jobs with or without matching keywords.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  once i get my data situated, it will be interested to check the performance between querying against the longtext vs querying against another table.  another variable that could affect the performance is the ability to do partial matches vs exact matches (ie, LIKE "%port%" vs ="portraits")

Comment: Why don't you give an example with indexing and against another table?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table_name]
WHERE keywords like '%portraits%'
  AND keywords not like '%outdoors%';
```